# How to set default page size for Pages '09?

Tags: pages

I'm not sure how I can set the default page size for Pages '09. For some reason, every time I set the page size as A4, it defaults back to US Letter.

I've tried setting these settings:

- Settings: Save as default
- Format For: Any Printer
- Paper Size: A4

But the settings won't let me choose the 'save as default' option and goes back to *Page Attributes*.

Answer (score 2):

change the region under *System Preferences* > International > Formats.
I believe that most of the region settings will cause Pages to default to ISO paper sizes (such as A4).
The only ones I know of which result in US Letter are *United States*, *United States (Computer)*, and Canada.

If all you care about is the paper size for new blank documents, you can always save a custom template with your preferred page setup, use that, and not touch your system settings.

Answer (score 1):

You could go to System Preferences » Print & Scan and at the bottom of the screen, there is a dialog box for "Default paper size". Select A4 there.

This should change the default page size across all programs, not just Pages.

Comment: Ah yes. I've tried this as well, but to no avail - US Letter was still the default option in Pages, for some reason.